# Wrong value for parameter "OTB folder"

Tags: qgis, mac, orfeo-toolbox

I have the latest QGis installed version 3.20 and the Orfeo toolbox should have come with it. I am working on iMac 2020 Big Sur version 11.4, there is no destination folder for the OTB:

[image]

When I activate by pressing on the button I get the following warning:

> Wrong value for parameter "OTB folder":
> '' does not exist. OTB provider will be disabled

Any ideas on how to progress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OTB doesn't come bundled with the QGIS install, only the ability to interact with it.

To install OTB you'll need to follow the OTB install instructions, which you can find here: https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Installation.html

I would recommend downloading and unzipping the package into your Applications folder as you can't move the package once it has been unzipped.

Once you've unzipped it the relevant folders for including in the processing menu options are:

Applications folder: /Applications/OTB-7.2.0-Darwin64/lib/otb/applications
OTB Folder: /Applications/OTB-7.2.0-Darwin64

You'll need to update the OTB version depending on which one you're using. And don't forget to tick "activate"

Answer (score 2):

For anyone revisiting this, I found this video useful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHTV40jScLI&t=216s

Comment: This didn't help me. I'm getting a strange error: 

"Couldn't load plugin 'auto_class' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'  "

It's even cazier because it says i'm using QGIS 3.22 and I just installed 3.28. I got both installed on my pc, but it doesn't seem to reognize the most recent one., even though I can open and use it normally. Anyone been through this?